# Javascript Google Maps in AS3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, google-maps

I have a standalone AS3 swf file that is using google maps via googles flash API.  Google will be shutting this API down in a few months and I need a solution.  Google now only supports the javascript version.  Is there a way to use this in the swf file?  I thought ExternalInterface.call would do it but I don't think it will work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible solutions off the top of my head that might or might not work. 1) Use Adobe Air which has a WebView class.  2) Overlay the map on top of the swf and use `ExternalInterface` for communication. And of course 3) rewrite the application in JS :(  Obviously none of these are great solutions though

Comment: solution 1 is very likely to work. any overlays there were wont work (or will need to be dealt in the html/js side), but it sounds reasonable. interestingly, isnt there some custom maps interface?